# Jackson - Deserialize using generic class

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I have a json string, which I should deSerialize to the following class

```
class Data <T> {
    int found;
    Class<T> hits
}
```

How do I do it?
This is the usual way

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, Data.class);
```

But how do I mention what T stands for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson - Deserialize Generic class variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659844/jackson-deserialize-generic-class-variable)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400850/is-jackson-really-unable-to-deserialize-json-into-a-generic-type

Answer (score 406):

You need to create a `TypeReference` object for each generic type you use and use that for deserialization. For example -

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Data<String>>() {});
```

Comment: I have to use it as TypeReference<Data<T>>(){} ... But I am getting the following error - cannot access private java.lang.class.Class() from java.lang.class. Failed to set access. Cannot make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible

Comment: No, not `Data<T>`, that is NOT a type. You must specify actual class; otherwise it is same as `Data<Object>`.

Comment: What if I dont know what class it is until runtime? I will get the class as a parameter during runtime. Like this     public <T> void deSerialize(Class<T> clazz {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.readValue(jsonString,  new TypeReference<Json<T>>() {});
    }

Comment: I have asked the full question correctly here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659844/jackson-deserialize-generic-class-variable

Comment: what's the full package name of `TypeReference`? is it `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type`?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, it seems to be

Comment: There is no need to define TypeReference type if your left-handed assignment reference has a type, just: `mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>() {});`

Answer (score 129):

You can't do that: you must specify fully resolved type, like `Data<MyType>`. `T` is just a variable, and as is meaningless.

But if you mean that `T` will be known, just not statically, you need to create equivalent of `TypeReference` dynamically. Other questions referenced may already mention this, but it should look something like:

```
public Data<T> read(InputStream json, Class<T> contentClass) {
   JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Data.class, contentClass);
   return mapper.readValue(json, type);
}
```

Comment: What if I dont know what class it is until runtime? I will get the class as a parameter during runtime. Like this     public <T> void deSerialize(Class<T> clazz {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.readValue(jsonString,  new TypeReference<Json<T>>() {});
    }

Comment: I have asked the full question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659844/jackson-deserialize-generic-class-variable

Comment: Then just pass the class as is, no need for `TypeReference`: `return mapper.readValue(json, clazz);` What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is that "Data" is a generic class. I need to specify what type T is at runtime. The parameter clazz is what T us at runtime. So, how to call readValue? calling it with new TypeReference>Json<T>> does not work The full question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659844/jackson-deserialize-generic-class-variable

Comment: Ok. Then you need to use `TypeFactory`.. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @StaxMan May I ask what you'd have as second argument in the readValue() method so as to return a List<T> ?

Comment: @StephaneEybert you'd need to use `TypeFactory` to construct the type; you can get an instance of factory from `ObjectMapper`

Comment: In Jackson 2.5 and above you should use `TypeFactory.constructParametrizedType` as `TypeFactory. constructParametricType` is deprecated.

Comment: @DavidV You mean the contrary? Anyway, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `constructParametricType` was briefly deprecated in 2.6 but only in that minor version: it replaces `constructParametrizedType()` which is deprecated.

Comment: This solution worked for me thanks @StaxMan

Answer (score 40):

First thing you do is serialize, then you can do deserialize.

so when you do serialize, you should use `@JsonTypeInfo` to let jackson write class information into your json data. What you can do is like this:

```
Class Data <T> {
    int found;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
    Class<T> hits
}
```

Then when you deserialize, you will find jackson has deserialize your data into a class which your variable hits actually is at runtime.

Comment: not working, getting below error
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class' (for POJO property 'data')

Answer (score 31):

From Jackson 2.5, an elegant way to solve that is using the 
[TypeFactory.constructParametricType(Class parametrized, Class... parameterClasses)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructParametricType(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class...)) method that allows to define straigthly a Jackson `JavaType` by specifying the parameterized class and its parameterized types.

Supposing you want to deserialize to `Data<String>`, you can do :

```
// the json variable may be a String, an InputStream and so for...
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Data.class, String.class);
Data<String> data = mapper.readValue(json, type);
```

Note that if the class declared multiple parameterized types, it would not be really harder :

```
class Data <T, U> {
    int found;
    Class<T> hits;
    List<U> list;
}
```

We could do :

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Data.class, String.class, Integer);
Data<String, Integer> data = mapper.readValue(json, type);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks it worked for me. With the typereference I got classcast exception from  map to the specific object but this really do the job.

Answer (score 16):

For class Data<>

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametrizedType(Data.class, Data.class, Parameter.class);
Data<Parameter> dataParam = mapper.readValue(jsonString,type)
```

Comment: This is now deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

Just write a static method in Util class. I am reading a Json from a file. you can give String also to readValue

```
public static <T> T convertJsonToPOJO(String filePath, Class<?> target) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(new File(filePath), objectMapper .getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Class.forName(target.getName())));
}
```

Usage:

```
List<TaskBean> list =  Util.<List<TaskBean>>convertJsonToPOJO("E:/J2eeWorkspaces/az_workspace_svn/az-client-service/dir1/dir2/filename.json", TaskBean.class);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap it in another class which knows the type of your generic type.

Eg,

```
class Wrapper {
 private Data<Something> data;
}
mapper.readValue(jsonString, Wrapper.class);
```

Here Something is a concrete type. You need a wrapper per reified type. Otherwise Jackson does not know what objects to create.

Answer (score 7):

JSON string that needs to be deserialized will have to contain the type information about parameter `T`.
You will have to put Jackson annotations on every class that can be passed as parameter `T` to class `Data` so that the type information about parameter type `T` can be read from / written to JSON string by Jackson.

Let us assume that `T` can be any class that extends abstract class `Result`.

```
class Data <T extends Result> {
    int found;
    Class<T> hits
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImageResult.class, name = "ImageResult"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NewsResult.class, name = "NewsResult")})
public abstract class Result {

}

public class ImageResult extends Result {

}

public class NewsResult extends Result {

}
```

Once each of the class (or their common supertype) that can be passed as parameter `T`  is annotated, Jackson will include information about parameter `T` in the JSON. Such JSON can then be deserialized without knowing the parameter `T` at compile time.
This [Jackson documentation link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) talks about Polymorphic Deserialization but is useful to refer to for this question as well.

Comment: and how do I manage this if I want to have a List?
Like let's say List<ImageResult>

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Data<T> extends JsonDeserializer implements ContextualDeserializer {
    private Class<T> cls;
    public JsonDeserializer createContextual(DeserializationContext ctx, BeanProperty prop) throws JsonMappingException {
        cls = (Class<T>) ctx.getContextualType().getRawClass();
        return this;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're using scala and know the generic type at compile time, but don't want to manually pass TypeReference everywhere in all your api l ayers, you can use the following code (with jackson 2.9.5):

```
def read[T](entityStream: InputStream)(implicit typeTag: WeakTypeTag[T]): T = {

    //nathang: all of this *crazy* scala reflection allows us to handle List[Seq[Map[Int,Value]]]] without passing
    // new TypeReference[List[Seq[Map[Int,Value]]]]](){} to the function

    def recursiveFindGenericClasses(t: Type): JavaType = {
      val current = typeTag.mirror.runtimeClass(t)

      if (t.typeArgs.isEmpty) {
        val noSubtypes = Seq.empty[Class[_]]
        factory.constructParametricType(current, noSubtypes:_*)
      }

      else {
        val genericSubtypes: Seq[JavaType] = t.typeArgs.map(recursiveFindGenericClasses)
        factory.constructParametricType(current, genericSubtypes:_*)
      }

    }

    val javaType = recursiveFindGenericClasses(typeTag.tpe)

    json.readValue[T](entityStream, javaType)
  }
```

which can be used like this:

```
read[List[Map[Int, SomethingToSerialize]]](inputStream)
```