# Preserve Generics when generating JSON schema

Tags: java, json, generics, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I'm using jackson-module-jsonSchema and jsonschema2pojo API.

Brief explanation: I'm trying to json-schemify my server's Spring controller contract objects (objects that the controllers return and objects that they accept as parameters) and package them up to use with a packaged retrofit client in order to break the binary dependency between the client and server.  The overall solution uses an annotation processor to read the Spring annotations on the controller and generate a retrofit client.

I've got it mostly working, but realized today I've got a problem where generic objects are part of the contract, e.g.

```
public class SomeContractObject<T> {
...
}
```

Of course, when I generate the schema for said object, the generic types aren't directly supported.  So when I send it through the jsonschema2pojo api I end up with a class like so:

```
public class SomeContractObject {

}
```

So my question is simple but may have a non-trivial answer: Is there any way to pass that  information through via the json schema to jsonschema2pojo?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class)?

Comment: That appears to be strictly focused on serializing/deserializing actual object instances.  I'm specifically looking at schema generation and then regenerating the actual java files

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with schema generation. Try on the github of the two projects, e.g., something like [this](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/151) or [this](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=generic). Sorry I can't be more hepful!