# Jackson: deserialize class that implements generic type

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization, jackson

I'm having troubles with jackson and generic types. I'll start by giving a simplified representation of my model:

```
package com.sample;

public abstract interface GenericInterface<T> extends Serializable {}

public abstract interface FooGenericInterface<T> extends GenericInterface<T>
{
    public abstract T fooMethod();
}

public abstract interface FooBar {}

public class Bar implements FooGenericInterface<FooBar>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected List<FooGenericInterface<?>> foos;

    public Bar() {}

    public Bar(List<FooGenericInterface<?>> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public List<FooGenericInterface<?>> getFoos() {
        if (foos == null) {
            foos = new ArrayList();
        }
        return foos;
    }

    public FooBar fooMethod() {
        for (FooGenericInterface<?> foo : foos) {
            foo.fooMethod();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = Id.CLASS)
public class FooObject implements FooGenericInterface<Object> {

    private String fooName;

    public FooObject() {}

    public String getFooName() {
        return fooName;
    }

    public void setFooName(String fooName) {
        this.fooName = fooName;
    }

    public Object fooMethod() {
        System.out.println("I'm FooObject " + fooName);
    }
}
```

The only code I can modify is the FooObject class. Now, I have an application (not mine) that deserializes Bar objects. I try to pass this json string to it:

```
{
        "foos": [
            {
                "com.sample.FooObject": {
                    "fooName": "Bob"
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

but i get this error:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type
>   id 'com.sample.FooObject' into a subtype of [simple type, class
>   com.sample.FooGenericInterface<java.lang.Object>]

Now, considering I can only edit the FooObject class (as the rest of the model is inside the third party deserialization app), how could I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271440/jackson-deserializer-for-generic-type?rq=1) help?

Comment: Actually not. The deserializer code is not something I can work on. It is contained in a third party web service application. But thank you anyway.