# I want through the Callback<T> to deserialize String to JSON , and I write this but i can't use

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

```
public <T> void getJsonObject(String res, RequestCallBack<T> callBack) {
    T result;
    if (res != null) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            result = mapper.readValue(res, new TypeReference<T>() {});
            callBack.onSuccess(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

it can't transmit `T` to the mapper the result is not what i want, what should I do?

Comment: T is not a type. You must specify actual class, otherwise it is same as TypeReference<Object> which gives you an unexpected result.

Comment: Actually it can be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class

Comment: thanks,but if I want  to through the RequestCallBack<T> to deserialize the string get the result ,how to write it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of libraries get around the type erasure by mandating the caller to pass the class in.

```
public <T> void getJsonObject(String res, RequestCallBack<T> callBack, Class<T> clazz) {
    T result;
    if (res != null) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            result = mapper.readValue(res, clazz);
            callBack.onSuccess(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, you probably shouldn't be creating a new ObjectMapper for each call (it can be an expensive operation).  I would suggest creating a single static one.

Comment: Thank you , I used another method to solve it, I deserialize the string in the RequestCallback so i can get the type of T and deserialize it.