# Java generics and jackson mapper

Tags: java, json, service, jackson, objectmapper

Hi I have the following classes:

```
public class MyRequest {
}
```

and

```
public class MyResponse {
}
```

and

```
public class Request<T> {
private String code;
private T request;

public setCode(String code) {
   this.code = codel
  }

public setRequest(T request) {
   this.request = request
   }
}
```

and following service request method:

```
public MyResponse getMyResponse(Request<MyRequest> myRequest) {
//process
try {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myRequest);
    System.out.println(jsonInString);
  } catch(Exception exp) {}
}
```

and following Json request is sending from JavaScript;

```
{
   "code":"TESTCODE",
   "request":null 
}
```

After I send the request I an getting an Invalid Json error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my request Json or something else is wrong..?

Comment: If you're positive that the generic isn't actually null, your problem is deserialization. This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class

Comment: where is the code which is deserializing your JSON from javascript?

Comment: Sending this using HTTP Request add-on of Firefox. This is not a full code... Previous code without Java generics was working perfectly.. Also Jackson is used on Spring side..

Comment: The error doesn't seems to be related to the code here as you don't have JSON at all. You are trying to write the object as a string which will have JSON structure but that's not the problem here

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you using the model 'Request' as an inner class. If yes,

- just try using the modifier static with 'Request'.
- or rather move out the model 'Request' to a separate class

Non-static Inner classes by design contain a reference to the outer-class, which does cause problems in deserialization.

http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html