# Get all the keys in a JSON string JsonNode in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonnode

I have a json string which I need to validate and find any other keys other than in a list is there in the json string. The sample json string is

```
{
    "required" : true,
    "requiredMsg" : "Title needed",
    "choices" : [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ],
    "choiceSettings" : {
        "a" : {
            "exc" : true
        },
        "b" : { },
        "c" : { },
        "d" : {
            "textbox" : {
                "required" : true
            }
        }
    },
    "Settings" : {
        "type" : "none"
    }
}
```

To allow only predifined keys is exsist in the json string I want to get all the keys in the json string. How can I obtain all the keys in the json string. I am using jsonNode. My code till now is

```
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(option);
        JsonNode reqiredMessage = rootNode.path("reqiredMessage");             
        System.out.println("msg   : "+  reqiredMessage.asText());            
        JsonNode drNode = rootNode.path("choices");
        Iterator<JsonNode> itr = drNode.iterator();
        System.out.println("\nchoices:");
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode temp = itr.next();
            System.out.println(temp.asText());
        }
```

How to get all the keys from the json string using `JsonNode`

Comment: do you want nested keys also. I mean `Settings.type` or `choiceSettings.exc`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Map<String, Object> treeMap = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);

List<String> keys  = Lists.newArrayList();
List<String> result = findKeys(treeMap, keys);
System.out.println(result);

private List<String> findKeys(Map<String, Object> treeMap , List<String> keys) {
    treeMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
      if (value instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
        Map<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap) value;
        findKeys(map, keys);
      }
      keys.add(key);
    });

    return keys;
  }
```

This will print out result as

```
[required, requiredMsg, choices, exc, a, b, c, required, textbox, d, choiceSettings, type, Settings]
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the `choiceSettings` keys `exc, a, b, c, required, textbox, d ` specifically or if I need` textbox` keys it sholud return `required`

Comment: el magnifeco! Thanks

Answer (score 16):

`forEach` will iterate over children of a `JsonNode` (converted to `String` when printed) and `fieldNames()` gets an `Iterator<String>` over keys. Here are some examples for printing elements of the example JSON:

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(option);

System.out.println("\nchoices:");
rootNode.path("choices").forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("\nAllKeys:");
rootNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);

System.out.println("\nChoiceSettings:");
rootNode.path("choiceSettings").fieldNames().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

You'll probably need `fields()` at some point that returns an `Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>>` so you can iterate over key, value pairs.

Comment: using rootNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(System.out::println); how to add the out put to list (List<String> allInput) instead of printing it

Comment: rootNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(oneInput -> allInput.add(oneInput));

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works out great but issues a warning, "Type safety: The expression of type `Map` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Map <String, Object>`"

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class) led me to change that line to the following to eliminate the warning:

```
Map<String, Object> treeMap = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

List in the json was not supported in the accepted solution. Here is what I propose:

```
public List<String> getAllNodeKeys(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Map<String, Object> treeMap = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {
    });
    return findKeys(treeMap, new ArrayList<>());
}

private List<String> findKeys(Map<String, Object> treeMap, List<String> keys) {
    treeMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (value instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
            LinkedHashMap map = (LinkedHashMap) value;
            findKeys(map, keys);
        } else if (value instanceof List) {
            ArrayList list = (ArrayList) value;
            list.forEach(map -> findKeys((LinkedHashMap) map, keys));

        }
        keys.add(key);
    });

    return keys;
}
```

Comment: - While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review]()