# Jackson ObjectMapper ignore certain keys when converting to POJO

Tags: java

Here is my class

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.*;

public class Util {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{ \"argA\" : 5, \"unneededkey\" : 6}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyObject object3 = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
        System.out.println(object3);

    }
    @ToString
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class MyObject {
        public MyObject(int argA) {
            this.argA = argA;
        }

        public MyObject(int argA, boolean argB) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argB = argB;
        }

        public MyObject(int argA, int argC, int argD) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argC = argC;
            this.argD = argD;
        }

        public MyObject(int argA, String argE) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argE = argE;
        }

        public int argA = 1;
        public boolean argB;
        public int argC = 4;
        public int argD = 5;
        public String argE;
    }
}
```

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) works but this ignores all unneeded keys. What if I only want to ignore certain unneeded keys and if I am given a key thats not part of my object constructor or in the unneeded set, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

My suggested approach:

Keep the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation on your class.

Assume the following input JSON:

```
{
    "argA": 5,
    "unneededkey": 6,
    "unexpectedKey": 99
}
```

Create a set containing the allowed field names (where "allowed" is a field which exists in your `MyObject` class, or it can be safely ignored):

```
Set<String> allowedFields = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(
            "argA", "argB", "argC", "argD", "argE",
            "unneededkey", "unneededkey2"));
```

Then process the JSON as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
Iterator<String> fieldNames = rootNode.fieldNames();
boolean fieldFailure = false;
Set<String> unexpectedFields = new HashSet();

while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
    String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
    if (!allowedFields.contains(fieldName)) {
        fieldFailure = true;
        unexpectedFields.add(fieldName);
    }
}
```

You can then choose how to proceed, based on the boolean `fieldFailure`. Either throw an exception (using the list of unexpected field names for information), or create your object in the usual way:

```
MyObject object = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
```

The down side to this is that it may traverse the JSON twice - once to check for problems, and again (assuming no problems) to deserialize the data.

*Points to note:*

(1) The above code assumes a flat JSON structure - no embedded objects - which matches what you have in your question.  For more flexibility, you can use the following `findKeys` method to recursively visit all nodes:

```
Map<String, Object> treeMap = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
List<String> keys  = Lists.newArrayList();
List<String> result = findKeys(treeMap, keys);

private List<String> findKeys(Map<String, Object> treeMap, List<String> keys) {
    treeMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (value instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap) value;
            findKeys(map, keys);
        }
        keys.add(key);
    });

    return keys;
}
```

Acknowledgement: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787047/12567365) for details.

(2) I considered a custom deserializer:

```
public class MyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Util.MyObject> { 
    ...
}
```

But you would still have the same issue - not to mention the extra work needed to invoke the correct constructor, depending on the specific combination of non-null field values it finds.