# How to convert LinkedHashMap to Map<String, Object> in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert a Map to Map. 
I have a json and Object :

```
{
        A: { availableInfo: { isAvailable : true} },
        VV: { availableInfo: { isAvailable : false} },
        B45: { availableInfo: { isAvailable : null} }
}
```

And the Object :

```
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AvailableInfo {

    @JsonProperty("isAvailable")
    private Boolean isAvailable;

    public AvailableInfo() {
    }
}
```

I tried :

```
Map<String, AvailableInfo>  response = getResponse(query, Map.class);
```

But I am getting Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to AvailableInfo
```

Below is the getResponse() method :

```
private <T> T getResponse(final RestURI query, final Class<T> responseClass) throws IOException {
        T response = null;

        final RestResponse<Record> tempResponse = client.call(GET, query);

        if (isResponseOK(tempResponse, query)) {
            byte[] payloads = {};

            for (Record rec : tempResponse.getResponses()) {
                final byte[] payload = rec.getPayload();
                payloads = ArrayUtils.addAll(payloads, payload);
            }
            final Reader reader = newReader(payloads)
            response = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(reader, responseClass);
        }

        return response; //returns Map<String, LinkedHashMap>
    }
```

Any idea how it can be resolved? I tried changing the input json to :

```
   {
            A:  { isAvailable : true} ,
            VV:  { isAvailable : false} ,
            B45:  { isAvailable : null} 
    }
```

But still not working.

Comment: The way I read that error message it's trying to cast the LinkedHashMap into the value.  So you might actually have a Map<String, LinkedHashMap> ... (left as an exercise for the reader to determine the types of the LinkedHashMap parameter - e.g. is it Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> or something else?

Comment: @Yeah. the json is Map<String, LinkedHashMap> which i am trying to convert to Map<String, Object>

Comment: How are you calling `getResponse`? What is the value you pass to `responseClass`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson - Deserialize using generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class)

Comment: This json:   {
            A:  { isAvailable : true} ,
            VV:  { isAvailable : false} ,
            B45:  { isAvailable : null} 
    }
 should return you Map<String, AvailableInfo>. What's the error you are getting with this?

Comment: @S.K. It saying java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to AvailableInfo

Comment: Hope you are calling getResponse(query, Map.class) with Map.class only. Can you point the line where error is seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your method signature to be

```
private <T> T getResponse(final RestURI query, final TypeReference typeReference) throws IOException {
    T response = null;

    final RestResponse<Record> tempResponse = client.call(GET, query);

    if (isResponseOK(tempResponse, query)) {
        byte[] payloads = {};

        for (Record rec : tempResponse.getResponses()) {
            final byte[] payload = rec.getPayload();
            payloads = ArrayUtils.addAll(payloads, payload);
        }
        final Reader reader = newReader(payloads)
        response = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(reader, typeReference);
    }

    return response; //returns Map<String, AvailableInfo>
}
```

and call it in the following manner

```
TypeReference typeReference  = new TypeReference<Map<String, AvailableInfo>>() {
    };
Map<String, AvailableInfo> map = (Map<String, AvailableInfo>) getResponse(typeReference);
```

using the following json example

```
 {
        A:  { isAvailable : true} ,
        VV:  { isAvailable : false} ,
        B45:  { isAvailable : null} 
}
```

i tried it and worked for me

Comment: this is output of println in console  

 {A=AvailableInfo@68be2bc2, VV=AvailableInfo@28feb3fa, B45=AvailableInfo@675d3402}

Answer (score 0):

First convert it using below line and then you can play with the data:

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>> resultList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
```

Comment: I am trying to get a Map<String, AvailableInfo>

Answer (score 0):

To convert the json into Map, the json has to be in the form of :

```
{
        A:  { isAvailable : true} ,
        VV:  { isAvailable : false} ,
        B45:  { isAvailable : null} 
}
```

After that following code returns `Map<String, AvailableInfo>` :

```
Map<String, AvailableInfo> readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

Output of `System.out.println(readValue);`:

```
{A={isAvailable=true}, VV={isAvailable=false}, B45={isAvailable=null}}
```