# How to handle parent child relation for Rest service

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

In my Spring boot service, I have a controller as below

```java
@PostMapping 
public ApiResponse generateUKLabel(@RequestBody LabelRequestData data){
  //do operation
}
```

Here, LabelRequestData has List of base class.
In, request I am passing child class data with base class data.
But, Child class data seems to be ignored.

Is there any way I can access the child class data.
I want to make the LabelRequestData with Base class generic so that it can accept multiple child class data.

Is there any way to solve it?

I tried casting. but throws can't cast exception 
I also tried generics. but then I need to create two controller method to handle those request. I want only one controller method to handle the request

```
@Data
public class LabelRequestData extends BaseRequestData {

    @Valid
    private List<BaseClass> labelData; // this base class has multiple child classes that i need

    @Valid
    private PreferenceData preferenceData;

}
```

Comment: Depends on what you are using as deserializer. Can be done in jacskon https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668644/1527544

Comment: have you tried using `List<T extends BaseClass> labelData;` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson - Deserialize using generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class)

Comment: I won't be able to use @valid now for validation if I am using json string as request body. Doesn't seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Deserialising the Jackson will not know which child class that has to be used, so it only takes the value of the `BaseClass` and ignores the `ChildClass`

You could use `@JsonTypeInfo` in the BaseClass , this helps the `Jackson` to identify the proper `ChildClass` (You have to add type in the json)

I am not sure what `BaseClass` holds so I am just assuming random attributes below.

#### BaseClass.java

```java
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildOne.class, name = "childOne"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildTwo.class, name = "childTwo")})
public class BaseClass {
    private Integer id;
}
```

#### ChildOne .java

```java
@Data
public class ChildOne extends BaseClass {
    private String name;
}
```

#### ChildTwo.java

```java
@Data
public class ChildTwo extends BaseClass {
    private String address;
}
```

If you request the Json,

```
{
  "labelData": [
    {
      "id": 0,                       //      -|
      "type": "childOne",            //       |-> This will go to ChildOne.class
      "name": "Foo"                  //      _|
    }, {
      "id": 0,                       //      -|
      "type": "childTwo",            //       |-> This will go to ChildTwo.class
      "address": "Somewhere in Earth"//      _|
    }
  ]
  // Rest of Json
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Is it possible to choose child class base on field value that belongs to PreferenceData class thats parallel to List<BaseClass>?