# How to deserialize JSON ? Cannot deserialize instance of `RegionResponse` out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have problems with serializing objects.
I trying to deserialize JSON. It contains lists :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "regionName": "Test",
    "regionWithType": "Resp Test",
    "regionType": "Resp ",
    "regionFiasId": "0c089b04-099e-4e0e-955a-6bf1ce525f1a",
    "regionCode": "19",
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": 23,
        "area": "Test1",
        "cityName": "Test1",
        "cityType": "г",
        "cityFiasId": "6b849aa8-0782-4c26-b7ac-a0f413f306c0",
        "cityKladrId": "16031",
        "cityWithType": "Test1"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "area": null,
        "cityName": "Kazn",
        "cityType": "г",
        "cityFiasId": "93b3df57-4c89-44df-ac42-96f05e9cd3b9",
        "cityKladrId": "1600000100000",
        "cityWithType": "г Казань"
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "area": "Test2",
        "cityName": "Test2",
        "cityType": "пгт",
        "cityFiasId": "c111218b-04db-4a5a-af50-aca9318791e0",
        "cityKladrId": "1600000100",
        "cityWithType": "Test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "regionName": "Test2",
    "regionWithType": "Test2",
    "regionType": "Респ",
    "regionFiasId": "6f2cbfd8-692a-4ee4-9b16-067210bde3fc",
    "regionCode": "02",
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": 343,
        "area": "Test1",
        "cityName": "Test1",
        "cityType": "г",
        "cityFiasId": "6b349aa8-0782-4c26-b7ac-a0f413f306c0",
        "cityKladrId": "0202300100000",
        "cityWithType": "Test1"
      },
      {
        "id": 344,
        "area": null,
        "cityName": "Test2",
        "cityType": "г",
        "cityFiasId": "35b3df57-4c89-44df-ac42-96f05e9cd3b9",
        "cityKladrId": "0200000100000",
        "cityWithType": "Test2"
      },
      {
        "id": 345,
        "area": "Test3",
        "cityName": "Test3",
        "cityType": "пгт",
        "cityFiasId": "c111218b-45db-4a5a-af50-aca9318791e0",
        "cityKladrId": "0200400000100",
        "cityWithType": "Test3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The error is

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `RegionResponse` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: (String)"[
{
"id": 1,
"regionName": " ",
"regionWithType": " ",
"regionType": " ",
"regionFiasId": "0c089b04-099e-4e0e-955a-6bf1ce525f1a",
"regionCode": "19",
"cities": [
{
"id": 23,
"area": " 1",
"cityName": " 1",
"cityType": " ",
"cityFiasId": "6b849aa8-0782-4c26-b7ac-a0f413f306c0",
"cityKladrId": "16031",
"cityWithType": " 1"
},
{
"id": 24,
"area": null,
"[truncated 1529 chars]; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
```

I don't want to change my object mapper because I use it in many other classes. My object mapper code :

```
@SneakyThrows
private CistomResponse processResponse(Class<? extends CistomResponse> responseClass, String body) {
  return objectMapper
   .readerFor(responseClass)
   .readValue(body);
}
```

In my response class, I want to serialize to list of objects (Regions) with a list of objects (City) :

```
@Getter
@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE)
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RegionResponse extends SdpResponse implements Serializable {

List<Region> regions;

  @Getter
  @JsonIgnoreProperties|ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static class Region implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("regionName")
    private String regionName;

    @JsonProperty("regionWithType")
    private String regionWithType;

    @JsonProperty("regionFiasId")
    private UUID regionFiasID;

    @JsonProperty|"regionCode")
    private String regionCode;

    @JsonProperty|"cities")
    private List<City> cities;

  @Getter
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static class City implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("cityName")
    private String cityName;

    @JsonProperty("cityFiasId")
    private UUID cityFiasID;

    @JsonProperty("cityKladrId"
    private String cityKladrID;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not an RegionResponse object. Where is regions field? It should be something like this:

```
   { "regions": [
  {
    
    "regionName": "Test",
    "regionWithType": "Resp Test",
    "regionType": "Resp ",
    "regionFiasId": "0c089b04-099e-4e0e-955a-6bf1ce525f1a",
    "regionCode": "19",
    "cities": [
      {
             
        "cityFiasId": "6b849aa8-0782-4c26-b7ac-a0f413f306c0",
        "cityKladrId": "16031",
        "cityName": "Test1"
      },
      {
                
        "cityFiasId": "93b3df57-4c89-44df-ac42-96f05e9cd3b9",
        "cityKladrId": "1600000100000",
        "cityName": "г Казань"
      },
      {
        
        "cityFiasId": "c111218b-04db-4a5a-af50-aca9318791e0",
        "cityKladrId": "1600000100",
        "cityName": "Test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    
    "regionName": "Test2",
    "regionWithType": "Test2",
    "regionType": "Респ",
    "regionFiasId": "6f2cbfd8-692a-4ee4-9b16-067210bde3fc",
    "regionCode": "02",
    "cities": [
      {
        
        "cityFiasId": "6b349aa8-0782-4c26-b7ac-a0f413f306c0",
        "cityKladrId": "0202300100000",
        "cityName": "Test1"
      },
      {
        
        "cityFiasId": "35b3df57-4c89-44df-ac42-96f05e9cd3b9",
        "cityKladrId": "0200000100000",
        "cityName": "Test2"
      },
      {
        
        "cityFiasId": "c111218b-45db-4a5a-af50-aca9318791e0",
        "cityKladrId": "0200400000100",
        "cityName": "Test3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Also object City doesn't have fields id, area etc.
As seems from the error response you tried to deserialize RegionResponse class object, not `List<Region>` object. So you have to deserialize it as `List <Region>` :

```
List<Region> h = new ObjectMapper().readValue(yourJSON, new TypeReference<ArrayList < Region >>() {
        });
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class) how to deserialize generic type.

Comment: yes, if I wrap with an object it works, but how can I do this without changing JSON ?

Comment: you can deserialize it as List<Region>, not RegionResponse because RegionResponse contains the regions field which is absent in the JSON

Comment: you can't deserialize JSON as List<Region> with your processResponse method because List<Region> class doesn't inherit CustomResponse class. It is a List which is a generic type