# How to use Jackson with a list that has a generic type

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize JSON into a list that contains a generic type.
The JSON I am getting from a partner is formatted like:

[
{
"topic" : "",
"valueSchemaId" : 48,
"key" : "",
"value" : {
"Name" : "test"
"Cars" : [
"Make" : "Dodge",
"Model" : "Charger"
]
},
"partition" : 1,
"offset" : 0
}]

However, the object in value can be of another type.   I created a Root class defined like:

```
public class RootModel<T> {
        public String valueName;
        public String key;
        
        public T value;
        
        public int partition;
        public int offset;
    }
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to map the Root and Value to the correct class.  For instance, if I were to create an instance of it I would `List<RootModel<PersonalData> personalDataArr = new ArrayList<RootModel<PersonalData>();` but I cannot figure out how to get Jackson to map to this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11664894/829571

Comment: Yoni, I think that may be what I am looking for.  I will play around with that

Comment: The main issue I run into when I attempt this is the data is all coming back as a List and I get an error when I tried this:  'List<RootModel<PersonalDataModel>> personalDataArr = objectMapper.readValue(personalDatajson, new TypeReference<List<RootModel<PersonalDataModel>>>() {});'   gets "Description Resource Path Location Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from RootModel<PersonalDataModel> to List<RootModel<PersonalDataModel>>"

Comment: Oops it should have been ArrayList not List

Comment: personalDataArr = objectMapper.readValue(personalDatajson, new TypeReference<ArrayList<RootModel<PersonalDataModel>>>() {});  works.  I can work with that.  Thanks for the link.