# How to decode generic data in Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

How can I do like this:

```
Test<String> data = OBJECT_MAPPER.decodeValue("sss", Test<String>.class);
```

When I call this operation I get an error. I need decode generic class.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you already read a simple tutorial like this https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial ? If so, what is your actual error? Or your actual question? Because `Json` doesn't exist in Jackson (as far as I know)

Comment: I can't get class from a generic class. For example, if I do Test.class it is ok, but I can't get class like this Test<String>.class // not working.

Comment: @Oleg, could you show your example `JSON` payload and `Test` class? `sss` is invalid `JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TypeReference`. `Test<String>.class` is not possible in `Java`.

```
TypeReference testStringType = new TypeReference<Test<String>>() { };
Object value = mapper.readValue(json, testStringType);
```

Also works:

```
JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Test.class, String.class);
Test<String> value1 = mapper.readValue(json, javaType);
```

See also:

- [Jackson - Deserialize using generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class)
- [Jackson - Deserialize Generic class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659844/jackson-deserialize-generic-class-variable)

Comment: @Oleg, no problem. I'm glad I could help. You can also change title to `How to decode geeneric data in Jackson?`. Generic in this question is a key word.