# Spring Boot consume REST API using class with generic field, which is not cast to proper type. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

*Example code below.*

Using Spring Boot 2.2, I want to communicatie with a REST API. the API I'm trying to consume wraps objects in a parent model for paging and sorting and puts an json array of the actual objects in the `results` field. How would I model my Java code so jackson 'knows' how to deserialize the API responses into my java objects?

**I've tried** solving this using an generic in ApiResponse, and passing the expected field-type when performing the get request:

```java
String URL_GET_DOGS = "https://localhost/api/v1/dogs/"
ApiResponse<Dog> response = this.restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_DOGS, response.getClass());
```

This compiles AND runs...

Expected result: Successfully created an ApiResponse object with a results field consisting out of a List of Dogs.

Actual result: Successfully created an ApiResponse object but the results field is a List of Objects.

So jackson won't **cast** the results list properly and instead I appear to get a `List<Object>` instead of `List<Dog>` for my `results` field in my ApiResponse Object. This way I end up with properties of the wrong Type or properties that I don't want to deserialize at all! See Car example.

Now I'm back to an interface-based solution but *I'm stuck.* Jackson (rightfully, because there is no way to deduce the correct class...) complains that it does not know how to deserialize abstract types and I would need to provide a concrete implementation, I can't use class-type Jackson annotations as described [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) because I do not control the API generating the responses.

The only way out of this I see right now, is to use classes for each type of response but that means a lot of duplicate code for paging and sorting fields. What am I doing wrong?

Example JSON:

```
{
    "count": 84,
    "next": "http://localhost:80/api/v1/dogs/?limit=2&offset=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Pebbles"
        },
        {
            "name": "Spot"
        }
    ]
}
```

and another endpoint:

```
{
    "count": 22,
    "next": "http://localhost:80/api/v1/cars/?limit=2&offset=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "brand": "Mercedes",
            "horse_power": 120,
            "field_i_dont": "want_to_deserialize"
        },
        {
            "brand": "BMW",
            "horse_power": 180,
            "field_i_dont": "want_to_deserialize"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example code:

```java
public class ApiResponse<T>{

    // paging and sorting
    private Long count;
    private String next;
    private String previous;
    // the actual objects
    private List<T> results;

    // No-args constructor, getters & setters

}

public class Dog {
     private String name;
    // No-args constructor, getters & setters

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Car {
     private int horsePower;
     private String brand;
    // No-args constructor, getters & setters

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Cause

Upon further investigation I found this is caused by Type Erasure, an answer [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11694447/11121415) provided a snippet to deal with this using Jackson.

From what I now understand the call to `response.getClass()` is exactly the same as calling `ApiResponse.class`. Even though ApiResponse was typed as a class with a generic parameter, generics 'lose' their type parameter because of a compiler rule called 'Type Erasure'. The Internal generic is converted to an Object type and Jackson will use a LinkedHashMap to represent any data in Object fields.

> Generics are used for tighter type checks at compile time and to provide a generic programming. To implement generic behaviour, java compiler apply type erasure. Type erasure is a process in which compiler replaces a generic parameter with actual class or bridge method. In type erasure, compiler ensures that no extra classes are created and there is no runtime overhead.
>
> Type Erasure rules
>
> - Replace type parameters in generic type with their bound if bounded type parameters are used.
> - **Replace type parameters in generic type with Object if unbounded type parameters are used.**
> - Insert type casts to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to keep polymorphism in extended generic types.

### Solution

In order to 'fix' the example in my original question

```java
ApiResponse<Dog> response = this.restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_DOGS, response.getClass())
```

Had to be changed so the raw JSON could be mapped using the `JavaType` class:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // Defined as final in rest-client class.
String rawJsonResponse = this.restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_DOGS, String.class)
ApiResponse<Dog> response = mapper.readValue(
    rawJsonResponse,
    mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(
        ApiResponse.class,
        Dog.class)
    );
```