# Jackson Deserialization By Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jackson, polymorphism, jackson-databind

I have a class with the following structure

`Class A {
private String type;
private T entity;
}`

And my JSON structure is like this

```
{"type":"Relation1","entity":"{..}"} --> entity should be Relation1.class
{"type":"Relation2","entity":"{..}"}  --> entity should be Relation2.class
```

How can I achieve the desired outcome using Jackson deserilizaton?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900902/1776132

Answer (score 0):

If you use inheritance in your model you can't obtain a clean json like showed because Jackson couldn't deserialize the json.
If you want to use Jackson you have to configure the ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

And then you will obtain a Json that include the T class name that is needed for deserialization process.

Here you find a complete guide: [Guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

Comment: Will it help If I change ``private T entity;`` to ``private AbstractRelation entity;``

Comment: No, I'm sorry.
But if Relation1 and Relation2 has the same fields you can set a concrete superclass Relation and put it in the model.
In this way your json will be clear and when you deserialize the json you will obtain a Relaction instance. then From the fields's values you can cast the instance to the correct RelationN class.